# An example of a topological space which is a group, but is not a "topological group"

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Is there any example of a topological space $X$ which has a group structure, but the maps $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ and $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ are not continuous?

Comment: The topology on the reals consisting of all sets that contain $5$. With the group structure given by addition.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Let $T$ be the collection of sets consisting of all sets which contain $5$. For example $\{0,\pi,\frac{1}{2},5\} \in T$ but $\{0,1.23,12\}\not\in T$. Then $T$ meets all the requirements of a topology.

Comment: Under Bill's example, the set $\{-5\}$ is closed (since its complement contains 5), but the inverse image of it under $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is $\{5\}$ which is not closed (since its complement does not contain 5, hence is not open). By the way Bill, you also need to state that the empty set is open.

Comment: Most of the group schemes are NOT topological groups.

Comment: @user40276 Could you elaborate?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft because they´re just group objects in the category of schemes over a final object and not in category of topological spaces (the product is the fiber product)

Comment: @user40276 The underlying set of a group scheme tends not to be a group either. An algebraic group (over $\mathbb{C}$) with the Zariski topology is closer to the spirit of the question.

Comment: @user40276 What Zhen Lin said was also essentially my thoughts. A group scheme need not be a topological group, but not in being a topological space where the group operations fail to be continuous. Rather, depending on your viewpoint, it might be neither a group nor a topological space (but rather a functor to the category of groups).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, but this is what I meant by writing that the product is the fiber product.